# Multiple group header suppression based on formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, suppression

I'm new to CR but am head report maker/editor.

I have a report where I have multiple headers (4) and a detail section that goes with each respective header.

i.e. GH3a goes with Details a, GH3b goes with details b, etc.

There is a previous formula created to pull {prm.analysis}{prm.method} as the "name" of that header (@GH1). The GH3 have (@GH1) at the top of the section and would be different based on the analysis being pulled.

GH3a-d (slightly different text headers per gh):

```
    @GH1
    Lab #    samp     client    result    comments
```

Detail section:

```
    lab #    samp       name    (blank)   (blank)
```

I need each GH and detail section to hide based off (@GH1).

I thought that using the following would work:

```
    if {@GH1} = "certain analysis and method"
    then true
    else false
```

It is in the section expert for each GH3 and Detail and each matching section has the same suppression code in it. I have tried reversing the true/false statements and that didn't work because then nothing showed up. I initially had this report only have GH3a and GH3b and it worked in that scenario. Then I needed to added 2 additional GH due to text header requests. I have issues getting the proper GH and details sections to suppress.

If it isn't possible then I can make separate reports but I don't want to clog up the report drop down for that report type.

[Print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL5zr.jpg)
[Report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmbv8.jpg)

Comment: Hey. I think it is possible and you will get help here. But your post is a bit confusing. Where did you put your formula?

Comment: Can you show design and what supression logic you are trying at what level

Comment: @heringer I apologize. I tried to explain as best as I could. The formula is in the group header body right above the text objects.

Comment: @siva I added an image link to the question at the bottom of the post. I was thinking I could use "if then else" for my suppression. I put the statement in the section expert in the "x-2" next to suppress (no drill-down) for both the group headers and the details sections.

Comment: Without supress conditon, how many GH1 are you able to see?

Comment: @siva in each GH3(a-d) there is 1 GH1 and it would be the same no matter which GH3 you look at. I can add an image of the print preview with no suppression to the post.